# NODE_PATH matches the npm root

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yeoman

I get this error when I try scaffolding a project using yeoman with this command.

```
npm install generator-gulp-webapp --global
```

The error:

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✖ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
npm global root value is not in your NODE_PATH
```

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and have not installed npm and node with the sudo command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems installing with

```
sudo npm install generator-gulp-webapp --global
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try with "Run as Administrator" option. It will work.