# Yoeman installation - [npm global root value is not in your NODE_PATH]

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

get:

```
✖ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
npm global root value is not in your NODE_PATH
```

during Yoeman installation

```
npm install --global yo generator-react-webpack
```

Comment: I literally Google'd your error and found this link: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/304. Pretty sure its for Mac but for Linux its the same. For Windows, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/7476755.

Comment: The error I got on Linux

Comment: Try this then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31234895/7476755. Seriously, use Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did:

```
yo doctor
```

and got recommendation for:

```
echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/pubudurw/local/install/node/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

source: [link](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/586)

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
yo doctor
```

After that it will indicate the same issue:

```
✖ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
npm global root value is not in your NODE_PATH
```

At the end line will have two suggestions to fix (related your home directories):

```
[Fix] Append the npm root value to your NODE_PATH variable
Add this line to your .bashrc
    export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/[YOUR HOME DIR]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules
  Or run this command
    echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/[YOUR HOME DIR]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Try to run the last one. Run the `yo doctor` again. The expected message will be(fixed):

```
Everything looks all right!
```